# Automounting external drives in Elementary OS

Tags: startup, disk-management

I've got a couple rsync scripts that I'm wanting to setup with my external drives, but I'm nervous that I'm going to blow something up if one of my drives isn't auto-mounted on startup. Earlier today, I was trying to do it manually, and I nearly blew up my perfectly setup Elementary by screwing with the fstab files, had to boot from the liveUSB, install gedit, and then navigate to go fix the fstab file.

Anyways, I wondered if there was an easier way, or if Elementary Loki might be integrating this into the System Preferences?

Answer (score 2):

Install gnome-disks using the command

`sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility`

The open it using `sudo gnome-disks`

Select the partition you want to mount. Click the `gear-icon` and the on `Edit mount options`

Disable the automatic mount option and Check the box stating `Mount on Startup`

Comment: in my case , this does not work for wine or virtualbox,the disks appear mounted in nautilus , but are still not accessible by wine or Virtualbox.

Comment: It mounts, but I have no write permissions